# How do I find and modify a pixel's RGB color using PIL's im.point()?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have an image ( gotten using `img = ImageGrab.grab( box )` ) and I wish to replace all pixels of a certain RGB value (precisely rgb(74,38,63)) with white and the rest with black.

The problem is that the image is in RGB, if it was in a single band (as i had earlier in the program) I could just use : `img2 = img.point (lambda i: i>254 and 255);` but this does not work with the rgb image, the `i` in the img.point doesn't seem to be a tuple of 3 ints (as I'd hoped it'd be) it's just the numbers 0 to 255 (if i didn't mess up somewhere).

Note, I don't want to use the `.getpixel()` method as it's too slow for what I want to do.

One alternative for my problem is using img.load() then working through the matrix of pixels myself, but I don't know how efficient this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy works very well for generalized fast and specific pixel manipulation.  Here's an example:

[image]

```
import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = Image.open("python.jpg")
a = np.asarray(im)

b = np.where(np.all(((a>[240, 40, 20]) * (a<=[255, 255, 150])), axis=2, keepdims=True), [80,0,0], [0,0,90])

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(b)
plt.show()
```

Here I converted a range of pixel values rather than a single value.  To do a single value, remove the use `==` rather than `>`, and only use one condition.  Also, I used matplotlib for an easy way to show the output and input together, but you could also convert back to an image using `Image.fromarray(b.astype(np.uint8))`.

Staying in pure PIL will work fine if you want to apply some simple standard filters, or use local `getpixel` operations, but for most numerical work with images, numpy or an image processing package is the way to go.